# Accessing EF Core Database on Startup to set constant values for Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, singleton

I have a set of constant values in a database. Ideally I'd like to read them once during startup to save going back to database each time. Currently have EF Core and would normally pass in IDbContext. To begin with I had:

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseConstants,DatabaseConstants>();
```

Then my Constants class would be

```
public DatabaseConstants : IDatabaseConstants{
    private int _value;
    public DatabaseConstants(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _value = dbContext.Table.Where( .... 
    }

    public int GetConstantValue() => _value;
}
```

But as its Scoped it would read from the database everytime I called **GetConstantValue()**.

I'm thinking I need something like this in my **DependencyInjection.cs**

```
services.AddSingelton<IDatabaseConstants>(new DatabaseConstants());
```

Then my Constants class would be

```
public DatabaseConstants : IDatabaseConstants{
    private int _value;
    public DatabaseConstants()
    {
        _value = ReadFromDatabase();
    }

    public int GetConstantValue() => _value;
}
```

Problem is I'm not sure how to access my database with this setup.

Does a pattern exist for reading from the database on startup?

Comment: Have look at [IServiceScopFactory](https://samwalpole.com/using-scoped-services-inside-singletons)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating the context in your constants class, instantiate it in a configuration class that is only called once, when the app loads. Add a method to your DatabaseConstants class to load the data, with the context as an argument, and call that method from the configuration class.